# How to select phone number from a paragraph using regular exp

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to select phone number from a paragraph.But the format of phone numbers are

```
123-456-7890
123.456.7890
123*456*7890
(202) 553-6381
123_456_7890
1234567890
1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.0
1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*0
954 665 53 92 
456 7890 x123
```

I got a regular expression but it not work in all cases.The regular expression is

```
$pat1="/(\d)?(0-9)|(\s|-|_|.|)?(\()?(\d){3}(\))?(\s|-|_|.){1}(\d){3}(\s|-|_|.){1}(\d){4}/";
```

Comment: And from where this paragraph is coming to you? If you can control the paragraph producer part then it is better to output in better parseable format rather than attempting to parse all these different formats.

Comment: Its a crawler program.I want to extract phone numbers from another site.

Comment: If I were you, I'd use different regex to match all the case before having headache :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the best but it will match all instances

```
(\d{3}([\-\.\*\s_]?\d{3})([\-\.\*\s_]?\d{4}))|\d(([\.\*]\d){9})|(\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}\-\d{4})|(\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{2})|(\d{3}\s\d{4}\sx\d{3})
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple uncompressed regex can be this:

```
^\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}|\d{3}\s\d{4}\sx\d{3}|\d{10}|\(?\d{3}\)?[\s-.*_]\d{3}[-.*_]\d{4}|(\d[*.]){9}\d$
```

note that in last line there is x123, if it is a four digit number you must change regex to:

```
^\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}|\d{3}\s\d{4}\s\d{4}|\d{10}|\(?\d{3}\)?[\s-.*_]\d{3}[-.*_]\d{4}|(\d[*.]){9}\d$
```

also, ^ means begins with, and $ means ends with. for some regex queries you must remove them.